# Invalid Character Error When Generating Tableau Hypers using API

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have a process that loops through several parquet files, converts them to CSVs, and then generates tableau hypers following the guidance provided here:
https://github.com/tableau/hyper-api-samples/blob/main/Tableau-Supported/Python/create_hyper_file_from_csv.py

However, for one of the files, I keep getting an error as the CSV is copied into the .hyper:

```
HyperException: invalid character in input string file:'/filepath/adds_time_of_day_error_drop_col.csv' line:2 column:12 Context: 0x5fdfad59
```

This is the schema of the problem parquet (before being converted to CSV):

[parquet schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygOhf.png)

The characters it calls "invalid" are decimals (e.g., 0.011 or 0.012) that worked fine in the other files I converted, so I'm not sure why it's not working here. Even when I drop the column, it just shifts the error over one column (so it would throw the error at line:2 column:11 instead of 12).

This seems similar to this issue on the tableau help forum, but I couldn't apply the solution there to this case because, as far as I can tell, there is no invalid character at line 2, column 12. I can't tell why **only** this CSV would have this issue when the others were created the same way with no problem.
https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000F33g5SAB/hyper-api-copy-from-csv-to-hyper-failed-with-context-0x5fdfad59

I don't think it has to do with the Table Definition because I've tried different SqlTypes for the column, and it always fails.

Comment: Try reducing the problem to the simplest case, say a CSV file with only one or two problem lines, possible just one or two columns. Sometimes the process of simplifying uncovers the oddity. Second, take a hard look at the offending line, and possibly surrounding lines, in a HEX Editor, to see if there are any strange unprintable characters nearby or other unusual things. Not an ascii text editor, but something that lets you see the actual hex code of each byte. For example, if you have two lines, one that works and a similar that doesn't, comparing them byte by byte can help uncover diffs.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and I'm guessing it's due to multiple datatypes in a single column (_Possibly having null values in the same column throws the error_
)